# Plugin Development - Call to undefined function comment_exists()

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, function-exists

In my plugin I hooked my function to `wp_loaded` and there is a call to the function `comment_exists()` which fires a **Fatal Error**. In which hook in the loading process I can be sure that the function would exist?

P.S.: I should hook my function to an action in loading process and before site is loaded completely.

Comment: How are you using this / could this be a namespace issue?

Comment: `comment_exists()` is definitely loaded before the `wp_loaded` hook. `wp_loaded` is fired on line 484 of wp-settings.php and `comment_exists()` is defined in a file that's loaded on line 180. So it sounds like either a namespace issue or you're using the function in a file outside WordPress.